# How to keep the footer element aligned?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to make my footer responsive so after reading and using some example I have make one but it's not as I want to.

I want to display the `Data protection disclaimer contact` in a row and not one upside one.

```css
.table {
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  clear: both;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  font-size: 14px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  z-index: 10;

  display:table;
  width:100%;

}
.table > div {
  display:table-cell;
  width:33%;
}

.table > .cell150 {
  width:33%;
}
.cell150:before {
  content:'';
  display:inline-block;
  width:33%;
}

.a{
  background-color: blue;
 }
 
.b{
  background-color: yellow;
 }
 
.c{
  background-color: pink;
 }
```

```html
<div class="table">
      <div class="cell150 a">
          V 1.1
      </div>
      <div class="cell150 b">
            Hi StackOverflow
      </div>
      <div class="cell150 c">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-8 col-md-4">
          <a href="/data_protection.pdf" class="footer-item hidden-xs" target="_blank">Data protection</a><a href="/disclaimer.pdf" class="footer-item hidden-xs" target="_blank">Disclaimer</a><a  class="footer-item">Contact</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Ok so here I don't know why it is displaying as I want to... but in my case it's like this:
[image]

Do you guys have an idea how to solve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this.

Change `col-md-4` to `col-md-12`

**note** : see the result in **full page** view

```css
.table {
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  clear: both;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  font-size: 14px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  z-index: 10;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.table>div {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 33%;
}

.table>.cell150 {
  width: 33%;
}

.cell150:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33%;
}

.a {
  background-color: blue;
}

.b {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.c {
  background-color: pink;
}

.footer-item {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="table">
  <div class="cell150 a">
    V 1.1
  </div>
  <div class="cell150 b">
    Hi StackOverflow
  </div>
  <div class="cell150 c">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-8 col-md-12">
      <a href="/data_protection.pdf" class="footer-item hidden-xs" target="_blank">Data protection</a><a href="/disclaimer.pdf" class="footer-item hidden-xs" target="_blank">Disclaimer</a><a class="footer-item">Contact</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but when I try the mobile view I can't see `disclaimer` and `data protection` it should put them one upside one or I don't know you understand what I mean ?

Comment: @Jerome If so then you have to remove the `hidden-xs` class

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="table">
      <div class="cell150 a">
          V 1.1
      </div>
      <div class="cell150 b">
            Hi StackOverflow
      </div>
      <div class="cell150 c">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="/data_protection.pdf" class="footer-item hidden-xs" target="_blank">Data protection</a> </li>
          <li><a href="/disclaimer.pdf" class="footer-item hidden-xs" target="_blank">Disclaimer</a> </li>
          <li><a  class="footer-item">Contact</a> </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px;
}

 ul li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 3px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this? Although in `xs` screen, they will be in separate lines

```css
.table {
text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  clear: both;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  font-size: 14px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  z-index: 10;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.table>div {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 33%;
}

.table>.cell150 {
  width: 33%;
}

.cell150:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33%;
}

.a {
  background-color: blue;
}

.b {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.c {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="table">
  <div class="col-xs-4 a">
    V 1.1
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 b">
    Hi StackOverflow
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 c">
    <div class="col-xs-12 ">
      <a href="/data_protection.pdf" class="col-sm-4 footer-item" target="_blank">Data protection</a>
      <a href="/disclaimer.pdf" class="col-sm-4 footer-item" target="_blank">Disclaimer</a>
      <a class="col-sm-4 footer-item">Contact</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you want, you can change the `col-sm-4` to `col-xs-4` to accomodate for the `xs` screens defined by Bootstrap, but you may need to adjust other css to display it properly